# Referencing a .net dll + unmanaged dll

Tags: c#, .net, dllimport

I have a project (call it platform) that references a .net dll (call it instrument-proxy), that reference a C++ dll using DllImport (call it instrument). The instrument and it's proxy are always the same version and are always deployed as one.

I need to be able to deploy several instruments (with their proxies) on the one machine, and only one platform that uses specific version of the instrument.

It seems like I cannot place an insturent-proxy to the GAC, as it uses a C++ DLL. I can install an instrument (and it's proxy) to a specific folder, but how can I ensure that platform will find that dll?

**Upd.**

The idea that theoretically I would like to see, is to reference this dll while development as normal, but to be able to make my application search for this dll in the custom folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For .Net assemblies you can subscribe to [AppDomain.AssemblyResolve](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.appdomain.assemblyresolve.aspx) and load the assembly when required using Assembly.LoadFrom (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/10120664/143503).

Comment: Wow! That is exactly what I was looking for. Actually I wasn't believed in your answer before I tried that. Pretty awesome.

Answer (score 2):

Keeping them in separate folders would be fine. You would load the right instrument-proxy assembly yourself using [`Assembly.LoadFrom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1009fa28.aspx). Then use reflection to create instance of a class from that assembly and make a call:

```
Assembly assm = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Versions\\Version01\\instrument-proxy.dll");
Type yourClassType = assm.GetType("YourClass");
object yourClassObj = Activator.CreateInstance(yourClassType);
object Result = yourClassType.InvokeMember("DoSomething",
                                            BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                                            null,
                                            yourClassObj,
                                            args);
```

To avoid reflection call `InvokeMember` you could try with interface:

```
Assembly assm = Assembly.LoadFrom("c:\\Versions\\Version01\\instrument-proxy.dll");
Type yourClassType = assm.GetType("YourClass");
YourInterface interf = (YourInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(yourClassType);
interf.DoSomething();
```

Interface would need to be in a separate assembly which you could reference from you `platform`. All `instrument-proxies` would have to be compiled against the same version of the interface assembly.

If your instrument-proxy can't find unmanaged `Instrument.dll` you can load it explicitly before first use:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

IntPtr pDll = LoadLibrary(@"PathTo_Instrument.dll");
```

Free/unload it after you're done:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
```

Comment: Yep, but I want to avoid using reflection. For example to be able to cast to YourClass I need to have a reference to the dll. Using your approach I cannot afford that, so I will need to use reflection for all calls, and that is very-very heavy and I definetely need to avoid that/.

Comment: I've added an update to the question, what is ideally and theoretically I need

Comment: You're right. I have changed the code but it is all reflection as you know. Will think about a solution but with dynamically loaded assemblies that's what you end up. Maybe performance would be acceptable? Worth a test.

Answer (score 1):

You can copy the unmanaged dll files to a folder and then add that folder to System Path Variable or you can copy these files to Windows\System32 , as this folder is always in the System Path.

To modify system path, Right click on my computer -> Properties -> Advance System settings -> Under Advance tab -> Environment Variables, there you need to find the path variable and then modify it to include your file.

Copying file to Windows\System32 or %systemroot% (C:\Windows usually) is easier though but I would recommend using the approach with Path variable modification

Answer (score 0):

Like Maceij suggests above, deploy your instruments in separate folders. But instead of using  reflection to load/instantiate the instruments, have a look at MEF.

Your exact needs may require another way to do this, but I would let the instrument-proxy `[Export]` an IInstrument factory interface with the following method:

```
IInstrument GetInstrument( string name, int major, int minor );
```

Then tell MEF where to find your instruments and let it create the different factories from which you then can request the instrument you need.

MSDN on MEF: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648.aspx